# Atlases on $S^{1}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, proof-explanation

I was thinking of the atlas of the circle $S^{1}$, I could not understand the solution in the book by Khan.

In the images attached - [image]

[image]

Why was $f_{U}$ taken different from $f_{V}$ ?
it could have been taken the same function?
is it not?

Also it is hard for me to think how it defined $f_{U} o f_{V}^{-1}$ in this way?
I got the identity part but how to get $id - 2 \pi$ on $(\pi, 2 \pi ) $ ?

Comment: Can I invite you to [Differential topology and Differential geometry Chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61560/differential-topology-differential-geometry-study-group), for discussing about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

$(-1,0)\not\in$ domain of $f_U$, i.e. the angle $-\pi$ is excluded. If you take the same definition for $f_V$, as this time $(-1,0)\in$ domain of $f_V$, you can't define $f_V(-1,0)$ because $-\pi\not\in(-\pi,\pi)$.